# Let $G$ denote the dihedral group $D_n$, $\rho$ a rotation of order $n$, and $\sigma$ any reflection. Prove that $\langle\rho,\sigma\rangle=G$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I can see how this is true for a given $n$, but need help in deciding how exactly this can be proved for the general case?

Also question about notation and its implications, does this mean that the exponent of $\rho$ must be equal to the exponent of $\sigma$ when multiplying them to get another element?

Comment: No, the exponents don't have to be the same. For example, you can have products such as $\rho^3\sigma$.

Answer (score 4):

The subgroup generated by the rotation has n elements, and the reflection is not in it. It follows that the subgroup generated by the rotation and the reflection has *more* than half the number of elements in the whole group. This can only happen if the subgroup is equal to the whole group.

Comment: Why exactly is this the case?

Comment: Why exactly is what the case? You need to specify exactly which step in the proof you don't understand.